# display something other than what is dragged in angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drop

I am trying to make a drag and drop where I want to drag something from one list and get something other as the dropped item. For eg, I want to grab branch from the left hand side and output two separate elements as in 'branched' on the right side. How can I achieve this in angular? Thanks

[see this ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4FLp.png)

Comment: Post some code and some attempts

Comment: see this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-kanban-szkkbf